# Not enough input arguments using radiomics package

Tags: matlab, input

I am trying to run GLCM using radiomics package (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51948-radiomics) using this code:

```
volume = double(rgb2gray(imread('http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~bruce/images/fall_2016_cs160/lectures/eye_pupil_tracking/grayscale_eye_cropped_to_bounding_box.png')));
mask = ones(size(volume,1),size(volume,2));
[ROIonly,levels] = prepareVolume(volume,mask,'Other','Matrix','Uniform',32);
[GLCM] = getGLCM(ROIonly,levels);
```

I get the following error:

> Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in prepareVolume (line 110)
>   if ~strcmp(textType,'Global') && ~strcmp(textType,'Matrix')
>
> Error in Untitled (line 7)
>   [ROIonly,levels] = prepareVolume(volume,mask,'Other','Matrix','Uniform',32);

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try to work around the arguments?

Answer (score 2):

The function definition for `prepareVolume` is this:

```
prepareVolume(volume,mask,scanType,pixelW,slices,R,scale,textType,quantAlgo,Ng)
```

The 8th input is `textType`.

You have only provided 6 inputs when you call

```
prepareVolume(volume,mask,'Other','Matrix','Uniform',32);
```

So the error exactly describes what has gone wrong

> Not enough input arguments.

Only the 9th and 10th inputs are optional, as captured by the 3rd actual code line in that function `if nargin > 8`. However, the first code line uses `textType` and always assumes it has been passed as an input.

Comment: 'Matrix' is the textType. If the case is that I have to fill all the 8-10 arguments what will be the pixelW,slices,R,scale for the png file that I wish to use?

Comment: I don't know, it depends what you want to do, you'll have to understand what the inputs do and apply that to what you want to achieve! MATLAB inputs are passed in order, currently `'Matrix'` is the `pixelW` input because you've passed it as the 4th input

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the error is caused by not providing enough input arguments to the `prepareVolume` function in the radiomics package. Specifically, the error says that there are not enough input arguments, which you can see [documented here](https://github.com/mvallieres/radiomics/blob/d3a61737730e1b2b46d04c9e22a3fcc390912f1a/TextureToolbox/Pre-processing/prepareVolume.m#L25) in the comments. Making easy to understand that the `prepareVolume` function expects 8 input arguments, instead of 6 arguments, as you provided.

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
% INPUTS:
% - volume: 2D or 3D array containing the medical images to analyze
% - mask: 2D or 3D array of dimensions corresponding to 'volume'. The mask 
%         contains 1's in the region of interest (ROI), and 0's elsewhere.
% - scanType: String specifying the type of scan analyzed. Either 'PETscan', 
%             'MRscan' or 'Other'.
% - pixelW: Numerical value specifying the in-plane resolution (mm) of 'volume'.
% - sliceS: Numerical value specifying the slice spacing (mm) of 'volume'.
%           Put a random number for 2D analysis.
% - R: Numerical value specifying the ratio of weight to band-pass coefficients 
%      over the weigth of the rest of coefficients (HHH and LLL). Provide R=1 
%      to not perform wavelet band-pass filtering.    
% - scale: Numerical value specifying the scale at which 'volume' is isotropically 
%          resampled (mm). If a string 'pixelW' is entered as input, the
%          volume will be isotropically resampled at the initial in-plane
%          resolution of 'volume' specified by 'pixelW'.
% - textType: String specifying for which type of textures 'volume' is 
%             being prepared. Either 'Global' or 'Matrix'. If 'Global', the 
%             volume will be prepared for Global texture features computation. 
%             If 'Matrix',the volume will be prepared for matrix-based texture 
%             features computation (i.e. GLCM, GLRLM, GLSZM, NGTDM).
% - quantAlgo: String specifying the quantization algorithm to use on 'volume'. 
%              Either 'Equal' for equal-probability quantization, 'Lloyd'
%              for Lloyd-Max quantization, or 'Uniform' for uniform quantization.
%              Use only if textType is set to 'Matrix'.
% - Ng: Integer specifying the number of gray levels in the quantization process.
%       Use only if textType is set to 'Matrix'.
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The error also indicates that the issue is related to the `textType` argument, which is the 8th argument in the function definition. Therefore, you should make sure that you provide all the required arguments, such as `scale` and `textType`, making sure to provide them in the correct order.

You have an example of usage of the `prepareVolume` function here:

```
[ROIonly] = prepareVolume(volume,mask,'PETscan',4,3.27,2,'pixelW','Global')
```

In this example, the `prepareVolume` function prepares the `volume` for global texture analysis at a scale equal to the in-plane resolution, with `R=2`. The function will return the `ROIonly` attribute, which is a 3D matrix that contains the extracted ROIs from the `volume`.